# How can I get the emacs command for a given keyboard shortcut?

Tags: emacs

Is there a general way to do this? I'm looking for a function that accepts an arbitrary keyboard shortcut, and returns the corresponding function name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> C-h k runs the command describe-key
>
> Display documentation of the function invoked by KEY. KEY can be any
>   kind of a key sequence; it can include keyboard events, mouse events,
>   and/or menu events.
>
> When calling from a program, pass KEY as a string or a vector.

Comment: This and `C-h f` for help about functions are *awesome*. It makes quickly writing random elisp functions really, really easy.

Comment: Also, `C-h c` runs `describe-key-briefly`, which outputs only to the echo area.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you really want a "function" rather than a "command" (i.e. something to call from Elisp rather than to use interactively), then `key-binding' is probably the closest.

Answer (score -1):

help for a command:

```
F1 + your command
```

doc for a command:

```
F1 + d + your command
```